Concatenation of fully connected ReLU neural networks

If $h_1$ and $h_2$ are fully connected neural networks in $\mathcal{FC} (Width=W_1,Depth=L,Input\ dimension=w_{in},Output\ dimension=w_{out}=w_1$) and $\mathcal{FC}(W_2,L_2,w_{in},w_{out}=w_2)$, then
$$
h(x)=\begin{pmatrix}h_1(x) \\ h_2(x)\end{pmatrix},h:\mathbb{R}^{w_{in}}\to\mathbb{R}^{w_1+w_2}
$$
is in $\mathcal{FC}(W_1+W_2,L,w_{in},w_1+w_2)$

Note that in this context the activation function is
$$
ReLU(x)=\max(x,0)
$$
I can't seem to wrap my head around this idea. As far as I know, a neural network is a composition of affine and activation functions. I don't understand how this concatenation gives us something of this sort. Maybe someone can break it down in a more 'explicit' way.

What source are you reading? Also, it is preferable to specify each part of $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{C},$ which appears to denote fully connected.

@sunspots I've added some details, I hope it is more clear now. Also, I'm reading the notes of a professor in my university, but I believe it is pretty standard when it comes to the basics.
